# Unable to resolve some dependencies when install Stormpath for .net core

Tags: nuget, .net-core, stormpath, project.json

When I install Stormpath for .NET Core through the package console I have these errors:

```
Unable to resolve 'Stormpath.Owin.Views.Precompiled (>= 0.4.4)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.

Unable to resolve 'Stormpath.Owin.Abstractions (>= 1.7.2)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.

Unable to resolve 'Stormpath.SDK.RestSharpClient (>= 0.94.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.

Unable to resolve 'Stormpath.SDK.JsonNetSerializer (>= 0.91.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.

Unable to resolve 'Polyglot (>= 1.2.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.

Unable to resolve 'Stormpath.Configuration (>= 6.0.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.

Unable to resolve 'Stormpath.SDK.Abstractions (>= 0.96.1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.
```

What can be the reason of these errors?

My project.json:

```
"frameworks":{
   "net452":{
      "dependencies":{
         "PhotoBooking.Contracts":{
            "target":"project"
         },
         "PhotoBooking.Data":{
            "target":"project"
         },
         "PhotoBooking.Domain":{
            "target":"project"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I copied your project.json contents from the comment you posted. If possible, can you edit your question and add the rest of your project.json file, not just the frameworks section?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .Net Framework in `project.json`

```
"frameworks": {
    "net452": {}
}
```

After that use `dotnet restore`

Comment: Thanks for operative answer! What dependencies i need to add? I'm sorry, i just begin work with this.

Comment: Like in post - `net452`

Comment: Please, can you write for me?

Comment: Example with dependencies

Comment: `"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {}, "net452": {}
  },`

Comment: "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "PhotoBooking.Contracts": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "PhotoBooking.Data": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "PhotoBooking.Domain": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },   this is what in project.json

Comment: @Yurimihnovec You can check more in official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#frameworks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in your package.json file. From the snippet you posted, it looks like your `dependencies` section is not in the right place.

From your question, I can't tell if you are building an ASP.NET Core application on top of .NET Core (`netcoreapp1.1`), or .NET Framework (`net452`). The Stormpath package will work in either scenario, though.

Here's a working project.json file for .NET Framework 4.5.2:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Stormpath.AspNetCore": "0.9.0",
    "PhotoBooking.Contracts": {
      "target":"project"
    },
    // your other dependencies here
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {}
  }
}
```

And for a .NET Core project:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Stormpath.AspNetCore": "0.9.0",
    "PhotoBooking.Contracts": {
      "target":"project"
    },
    // your other dependencies here
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": "dotnet"
    }
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the package author.